# Problem with DateTime::Event::Sunrise

Tags: perl, datetime

[DateTime::Event::Sunrise](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aEvent%3a%3aSunrise)
Why do I get here the message "Can't locate object method "sunrise_datetime" via package "DateTime::Set""

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Event::Sunrise;

my $dt = DateTime->new( year => 2010, month => 12, day => 22, time_zone => 'CET' );

my $longitude = 16;
my $latitude = 48;
my $sunrise = DateTime::Event::Sunrise ->sunrise (
    longitude => $longitude,
    latitude => $latitude,
    altitude => '-0.833',
    iteration => '1'
);
my $sunset = DateTime::Event::Sunrise ->sunset (
    longitude => $longitude,
    latitude => $latitude,
    altitude => '-0.833',
    iteration => '1'
);

my $dt1 = $sunrise->sunrise_datetime( $dt );
say "Sunrise is:", $dt1->datetime;
my $dt2 = $sunrise->sunset_datetime( $dt );
say "Sunset is:",  $dt2->datetime;

# Can't locate object method "sunrise_datetime" via package "DateTime::Set" at ./so.pl line 24.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation seems wrong on this one.  The source has it better:

```
# FUNCTIONAL SEQUENCE for sunrise_sunset 
#
# _GIVEN
# 
# A sunrise class
# A DateTime object
# 
# _THEN
#
#  Validate the DateTime object is valid  
#  Compute sunrise and sunset  
#      
#
# _RETURN
#
#  DateTime object that contains the rise times
```

The important part is that the object you invoke it on must be of class `DateTime::Event::Sunrise`.  Your `$sunrise` object is of class `DateTime::Set`.

You could get it to work by either creating `$sunrise` as a `DateTime::Event::Sunrise`:

```
my $sunrise = DateTime::Event::Sunrise->new(
    longitude => $longitude,
    latitude => $latitude,
    altitude => '-0.833',
    iteration => '1'
);
```

Or by using the iteration facilities provided by `DateTime::Set` instead:

```
my $dt1 = $sunrise->next( $dt ); # or current, closest...
```

Comment: "Notes on iteration ... If you want higher accuracy, you must then use the iteration feature. ...".  Do I use with "my $dt1 = $sunrise->next( $dt );" the iteration feature quoted above?

Comment: It would probably be advisable to send in a bug report for this to the module maintainers. There is also a datetime mailing list that you could use.

Comment: @Ether: There are 6 years old active bugs in the bug-report-section - does that mean that the module is no longer maintained?

Comment: @sid: possibly, but you should send something to the mailing list to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for that module is terrible. But I think that you want the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Event::Sunrise;

my $dt = DateTime->new( year => 2010, month => 12, day => 22, time_zone => 'CET' );

my $longitude = 16;
my $latitude = 48;
my $sunrise = DateTime::Event::Sunrise ->sunrise (
    longitude => $longitude,
    latitude => $latitude,
    altitude => '-0.833',
    iteration => '1'
);
my $sunset = DateTime::Event::Sunrise ->sunset (
    longitude => $longitude,
    latitude => $latitude,
    altitude => '-0.833',
    iteration => '1'
);

my $dt1 = $sunrise->next($dt);
say "Sunrise is: ", $dt1->datetime;
my $dt2 = $sunset->next($dt);
say "Sunset is: ",  $dt2->datetime;
```

Which returns this:

```
$ ./sunrise 
Sunrise is: 2010-12-22T07:43:20
Sunset is: 2010-12-22T16:05:30
```

Comment: Now I would say the documentation is even wrong ( concerning my example ).